# is there a way hiding login credentials from test script in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, obscured-view

A script has been written to access a website programatically(sending a get request) that requires user login credentials, and so the same has been hardcoded in the script.Is there a way in python to hide these credentials from the test script?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PasswordVault

Alternatively, if your script is only going to run on one server, you could keep the credentials in the environment variables on that machine and make the script refer to those variables.